# issue about iOS Core Location GPS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

When initializing a new class, which methods of this class will be executed automatically.. Please take a look at codes below:

CoreLocationDemoViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"CORE_LOCATION_DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER=======>VIEW_DID_LOAD");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init]; // line 1
    CLController.delegate = self;                         // line 2
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

CoreLocationController.m

```
- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"CORE_LOCATION_CONTROLLER=======>INIT"); 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
   NSLog(@"CORE_LOCATION_CONTROLLER=======>DID_UPDATE_TO_LOCATION");
}
```

From debugging, I got

```
2011-10-11 23:44:31.682 CoreLocationDemo[77470:207] CORE_LOCATION_CONTROLLER=======>INIT
2011-10-11 23:44:31.707 CoreLocationDemo[77470:207] CORE_LOCATION_CONTROLLER=======>DID_UPDATE_TO_LOCATION
```

It seems that **init** and **locationManager** are executed automatically...I am not so sure about this...

Another question is at line 2, what

```
CLController.delegate = self ( delegate is declared as  id delegate  in CoreLocationController.h )
```

does

Please help if you were experiencing before and all comments are welcomed here

Answer (score 0):

init() is called because of this

```
CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
```

didUpdateToLocation is called because of this as a delegate call back

```
[CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

As a sidenote, I am noticing your init neither calls super init nor returns self. I guess you trimmed down that for the post.

Comment: You are not directly calling the didUpdateToLocation, since you are calling CLLocationManager (locMgr) 's startUpdatingLocation, the locationmanager would call the delegate method didUpdateToLocation when it gets a locationFix. Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html. Also read in general how delegate works.